# solving utopian tree , what is wrong with code?

Tags: c++, c

The code takes a number as input and returns a number output according to the given series:

**Input**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

**Output**

```
2 3 6 7 14 15 30 31 62
```

**The Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int test,y[10],i,j,newvalue = 0;
    scanf("%d",&test);

    for( i=1;i<=test;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d\n",&y[i]);
        for ( j=0 ; j<=y[i] ;j++)
        {
            if ( j %2 ==0)
                newvalue =newvalue +1;
            else
                newvalue = newvalue*2;
        }
        printf("%d\n",newvalue); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please tell us first what's wrong with the output.

Comment: Does it compile? Does it crash? Does it give wrong output? What's wrong?

Comment: I guess the input for `test` variable of code is missing in the given input condition which must be 9!

Comment: @shekharsuman the idea of asking question is that we don't have to guess what the question really is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int test,y[10],i,j;
    scanf("%d",&test);

    for( i=1;i<=test;i++)
    {
        int newvalue = 0; //Here
        scanf("%d\n",&y[i]);
        for ( j=0 ; j<=y[i] ;j++)
        {
            if ( j %2 ==0)
                newvalue =newvalue +1;
            else
                newvalue = newvalue*2;
        }
        printf("%d\n",newvalue); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you all for the inputs....sorry i didn't explain my question well but i got my answer :)

Comment: `scanf("%d\n",&y[i]);` -> `scanf("%d",&y[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
for ( j=0 ; j<=y[i] ;j++)
{
     if ( j %2 ==0)
         newvalue =newvalue +1;
     else
         newvalue = newvalue*2;
}
```

To

```
if ( y[i] %2 ==0)
     newvalue =newvalue +1;
else
     newvalue = newvalue*2;
```

**Try this code:**

```
int main()
{
    int test,y[10],i,j,newvalue = 0;
    scanf("%d",&test);

    for( i=1;i<=test;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d\n",&y[i]);
        if ( y[i] %2 ==0)
            newvalue =newvalue +1;
        else
            newvalue = newvalue*2;
        printf("%d\n",newvalue); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, rename 'test' to 'numberOfOutputs' or 'numberOfInputs' to clarify your code.

I have no clue what your y[] array is used for, so provide a descriptive name for that one too. Is it that you want to display 10 differently calculated numbers?

Also a 'for-loop' that starts at 0 and uses '<=' is suspicious. Probably you need only '<'.

I also don't understand what you want to do with the newValue initialisation. You may want to move that into the second for loop. Otherwise, it will all accumulate.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int num, i,max = 0, newvalue = 1;

    scanf("%d", &num);
    int in[num];

    for(i=0;i<num;++i){
        scanf("%d", &in[i]);
        if(max < in[i])
            max = in[i];
    }
    int seq[max];
    for(i=1;i<=max;++i){
        if(i % 2 == 0)
            newvalue = newvalue + 1;
        else 
            newvalue = newvalue * 2;
        seq[i-1] = newvalue; 
    }
    for(i=0;i<num;++i)
        printf("%d ", seq[in[i]-1]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```